# Mysql Timestamp and Var

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, varchar, difference

I have I'm having to workout the days difference between 2 columns one of which is a timestamp and the other being a varchar

**timestamp** -  2016-01-25 23:55:23 and **varchar** - 24/12/2015

not the best format for dates, but given that I'm unable to change the columns type is it possible to work out the difference in days between those 2 columns?

Many thanks
Max

Comment: Mysql has its own function `str_to_date` which would help you to convert a string to a real date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime` Class in PHP is very powerful and flexible, specially using the `createFromFormat()` method to load dates of different formats quite happily. Used together with the `->diff()` method you should get what you want.

Here is an example

```
<?php
$ts = '2016-01-25 23:55:23';
$vc = '24/12/2015';

$tsdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
$vcdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $vc);

$interval = $vcdate->diff($tsdate);

echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Alternatively you could get MYSQL to do the heavy lifting and use its `STR_TO_DATE()` function when you query this odd varchar field

```
SELECT tsCol, STR_TO_DATE(varcharColumn, '%d/%m/%Y) as otherDate
```

Then when you see it in PHP it will be converted to a MySQL `DATETIME` column

Or going even further and getting MySQL to do all the work you could use MySQL's `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, tsCol, STR_TO_DATE(varcharColumn, '%d/%m/%Y)) as differenceInDays;
```

Comment: that worked a treat! i used the php method for the conversion..big thank you!